# JavaScript form validation issue: Alert for same answers for MOST and LEAST

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a HTML and JavaScript form for a personality test, and I'm encountering issues with validation. The form has multiple questions with both "MOST" and "LEAST" radio button options.

Issue 1: I want to alert the user if they select the same answer (either "MOST" or "LEAST") for a question.

I've tried implementing various solutions, but I'm still facing problems.

I aim to alert users if they selected the same answer (either "MOST" or "LEAST") for a question.

I've added the screenshot of the HTML for 1 question
[HTML Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsC12.png)

This is the Javascript:

```
`var DiscModule = (function() {
    var d, i, s, c, d2, i2, s2, c2;
    
    function getScores() {
        d = i = s = c = 0;
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
        for (var count = 0, l = inputs.length; count < l; count++) {
            if (inputs[count].checked) {
                switch (inputs[count].value) {
                    case "d-most": d++; break;
                    case "i-most": i++; break;
                    case "s-most": s++; break;
                    case "c-most": c++; break;
                    case "d-least": d--; break;
                    case "i-least": i--; break;
                    case "s-least": s--; break;
                    case "c-least": c--; break;
                }
            }
        }

        // checks if all questions are answered
        return (d !== 0 && i !== 0 && s !== 0 && c !== 0);
    }
        // calculations for the test
    function calculateWeightedScores() {
        if (d >= 6) d2 = 7;
        else if (d >= -1) d2 = 6;
        else if (d >= -5) d2 = 5;
        else if (d >= -9) d2 = 4;
        else if (d >= -13) d2 = 3;
        else if (d >= -16) d2 = 2;
        else d2 = 1;
        
        if (i >= 8) i2 = 7;
        else if (i >= 5) i2 = 6;
        else if (i >= 2) i2 = 5;
        else if (i >= -1) i2 = 4;
        else if (i >= -4) i2 = 3;
        else if (i >= -8) i2 = 2;
        else i2 = 1;
        
        if (s >= 12) s2 = 7;
        else if (s >= 8) s2 = 6;
        else if (s >= 5) s2 = 5;
        else if (s >= 1) s2 = 4;
        else if (s >= -2) s2 = 3;
        else if (s >= -7) s2 = 2;
        else s2 = 1;
        
        if (c >= 6) c2 = 7;
        else if (c >= 3) c2 = 6;
        else if (c >= -1) c2 = 5;
        else if (c >= -3) c2 = 4;
        else if (c >= -7) c2 = 3;
        else if (c >= -11) c2 = 2;
        else c2 = 1;
    }
    
    function createCharts() {
        var total = 7;
        
        document.querySelector("#d-chart").style.width = (d2 / total * 100) + "%";
        document.querySelector("#i-chart").style.width = (i2 / total * 100) + "%";
        document.querySelector("#s-chart").style.width = (s2 / total * 100) + "%";
        document.querySelector("#c-chart").style.width = (c2 / total * 100) + "%";
    }
    
    function showResults() {
        document.querySelector("#d-score").innerHTML = d2;
        document.querySelector("#i-score").innerHTML = i2;
        document.querySelector("#s-score").innerHTML = s2;
        document.querySelector("#c-score").innerHTML = c2;
        document.querySelector("#scroll-down").classList.remove("hidden");

    
    }
    return {
        processForm: function() {
            if (getScores()) {
                calculateWeightedScores();
                createCharts();
                showResults();
            } else {
                alert("Please answer all questions before calculating results.");
            }
        }
    };
})();

document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = function() {
    DiscModule.processForm();
};`
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Triven - DISC Test</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>

<!-- Questions-->

<div class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="page-header col-xs-12">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll-down" class="hidden">
    </div>    
    <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <span class="badge">1</span><br><br>
                Enthusiastic<br>
                Daring<br>
                Diplomatic<br>
                Satisfied
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                MOST<br><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="i-most"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="d-most"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="c-most"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="s-most">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                LEAST<br><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="i-least"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="d-least"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="c-least"><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="s-least">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please insert HTML/JavaScript/CSS code in the code snippet instead of attaching the image of code.

Comment: I have already insert the code for HTML and JS in the code snippet

Comment: why can you select both `most` and `least` for a question? Please add sufficient HTML to actually allow others to see the problem and build a working snippet

Comment: is that sufficient enough? hopefully it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does what you need - if the user selects both "Most" & "Least" for a particular option in a particular question ( hard to test with only a single question ) then an alert warning the user will be displayed.

This is achieved here using a global variable (within scope of the `DiscModule` function ) that is initialised as an object literal and entries within as scoped as arrays. These arrays hold the "Most" / "Least" values selected per question - two the same mean the user selected an illegal pairing.

It feels like this could be refined perhaps.

```js
var DiscModule = (function() {
  var d, i, s, c, d2, i2, s2, c2;
  let pairs={};
  
  function getScores() {
    d = i = s = c = 0;
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    for ( var count = 0, l = inputs.length; count < l; count++ ) {
      if ( inputs[count].checked ) {
      
        /* 
          It is easier to work with name/value than inputs[count].name etc 
          and we can ignore text such as most & least as we need a unique
          name for key in pairs object.
        */
        let name=inputs[count].name.replace(/(most|least)/gi,'');
        let value=inputs[count].value;
        /*
          Create an array within the pairs object to store values
          of both MOST / LEAST
        */
        if( !Array.isArray( pairs[ name ] ) )pairs[ name ]=[];
        /*
          push the letter character into array
          - if there are two the same later then the user has mucked up!
        */
        pairs[ name ].push( value.replace(/(most|least|-)/gi,'')  )


        switch(value) {
          case "d-most":
            d++;
          break;
          case "i-most":
            i++;
          break;
          case "s-most":
            s++;
          break;
          case "c-most":
            c++;
          break;
          case "d-least":
            d--;
          break;
          case "i-least":
            i--;
          break;
          case "s-least":
            s--;
          break;
          case "c-least":
            c--;
          break;
        }

        if( Object.keys( pairs[ name ] ).length==2 ){
          if( pairs[ name ][ 0 ]==pairs[ name ] [ 1 ] ){
            pairs={};
            alert('\nComputer says No!\n\nYou cannot answer both "Most" & "Least" for the same option...');
            return
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    // return here because insufficient questions posted by @OP
    return true;

    // checks if all questions are answered
    return (d !== 0 && i !== 0 && s !== 0 && c !== 0);
  }
  // calculations for the test
  function calculateWeightedScores() {
    if (d >= 6) d2 = 7;
    else if (d >= -1) d2 = 6;
    else if (d >= -5) d2 = 5;
    else if (d >= -9) d2 = 4;
    else if (d >= -13) d2 = 3;
    else if (d >= -16) d2 = 2;
    else d2 = 1;

    if (i >= 8) i2 = 7;
    else if (i >= 5) i2 = 6;
    else if (i >= 2) i2 = 5;
    else if (i >= -1) i2 = 4;
    else if (i >= -4) i2 = 3;
    else if (i >= -8) i2 = 2;
    else i2 = 1;

    if (s >= 12) s2 = 7;
    else if (s >= 8) s2 = 6;
    else if (s >= 5) s2 = 5;
    else if (s >= 1) s2 = 4;
    else if (s >= -2) s2 = 3;
    else if (s >= -7) s2 = 2;
    else s2 = 1;

    if (c >= 6) c2 = 7;
    else if (c >= 3) c2 = 6;
    else if (c >= -1) c2 = 5;
    else if (c >= -3) c2 = 4;
    else if (c >= -7) c2 = 3;
    else if (c >= -11) c2 = 2;
    else c2 = 1;
  }

  function createCharts() {
    var total = 7;

    document.querySelector("#d-chart").style.width = (d2 / total * 100) + "%";
    document.querySelector("#i-chart").style.width = (i2 / total * 100) + "%";
    document.querySelector("#s-chart").style.width = (s2 / total * 100) + "%";
    document.querySelector("#c-chart").style.width = (c2 / total * 100) + "%";
  }

  function showResults() {
    document.querySelector("#d-score").innerHTML = d2;
    document.querySelector("#i-score").innerHTML = i2;
    document.querySelector("#s-score").innerHTML = s2;
    document.querySelector("#c-score").innerHTML = c2;
    document.querySelector("#scroll-down").classList.remove("hidden");


  }
  return {
    processForm: function() {
      if (getScores()) {
        calculateWeightedScores();
        createCharts();
        showResults();
        pairs={};
      } else {
        alert("Please answer all questions before calculating results.");
      }
    }
  };
})();

document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = function() {
  DiscModule.processForm();
};
```

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5em Lato, sans-serif;
}

.q {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.q:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.pull-left {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700'>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-header col-xs-12">
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll-down" class="hidden"></div>
    <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <span class="badge">1</span><br>
          <br> Enthusiastic
          <br> Daring
          <br> Diplomatic
          <br> Satisfied
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
          MOST<br><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="i-most"><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="d-most"><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="c-most"><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="s-most">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
          LEAST<br><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="i-least"><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="d-least"><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="c-least"><br>
          <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="s-least">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Progress Bar-->

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <br>
      <p class="text-center"><button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Calculate Results</button></p>
      <div id="results">
        <div class="pull-left"><span class="badge">D</span> (<span id="d-score"></span>)</div>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="d-chart" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-left"><span class="badge">I</span> (<span id="i-score"></span>)</div>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="i-chart" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-left"><span class="badge">S</span> (<span id="s-score"></span>)</div>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="s-chart" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-left"><span class="badge">C</span> (<span id="c-score"></span>)</div>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="c-chart" class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**updated version**

```js
class DiscModule {
  constructor() {
    this.total = 7;
    this.results = {
      d: 0,
      i: 0,
      s: 0,
      c: 0
    };
    this.scores = {
      d: 0,
      i: 0,
      s: 0,
      c: 0
    };
    this.matrix = {
      'd': {
        '6': 7,
        '-1': 6,
        '-5': 5,
        '-9': 4,
        '-13': 3,
        '-16': 2
      },
      'i': {
        '8': 7,
        '5': 6,
        '2': 5,
        '-1': 4,
        '-4': 3,
        '-8': 2
      },
      's': {
        '12': 7,
        '8': 6,
        '5': 5,
        '1': 4,
        '-2': 3,
        '-7': 2
      },
      'c': {
        '6': 7,
        '3': 6,
        '-1': 5,
        '-3': 4,
        '-7': 3,
        '-11': 2
      }
    };
    this.pttn = /(most|least|-)/gi;
    this.pairs = {};
    this.errors = [];
    this.warning = 'It does not make sense to select both "Most" & "Least" for the same option!';
  };

  clearerrors() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.error').forEach(n => n.classList.remove('error'))
  };
  seterror(n) {
    n.closest('div.row').parentNode.classList.add('error');
  };

  logscore(name, value) {
    if (!Array.isArray(this.pairs[name])) this.pairs[name] = [];
    this.pairs[name].push(value.replace(this.pttn, ''));

    if (this.pairs[name].length == 2) {
      if (new Set(this.pairs[name]).size == 1) {
        this.errors.push(name);
        return name; //effectively "true"
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  validate() {
    let all = [...document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]')].length;
    let checked = [...document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]:checked')].length;
    return ((all / 4) == checked);
  };

  getscores() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.validate()) reject({
        type: 1,
        message: 'Please answer all questions'
      });

      this.clearerrors();

      document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]:checked').forEach(n => {
        let name = n.name.replace(this.pttn, '');
        let value = n.value;

        if (this.logscore(name, value)) {
          this.seterror(n);
        }

        let [chr, verb] = value.split('-');
        let i = verb == 'most' ? 1 : -1;
        this.scores[chr] += i;
      });

      if (this.errors.length > 0) reject({
        type: 2,
        message: this.errors.join(', ')
      });
      resolve(this.scores);
    });
  };

  calculate(b) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Object.keys(this.scores).forEach(key => {
        let score = this.scores[key];
        let matrix = this.matrix[key];
        let keys = Object.keys(matrix);
        let v = 1; // default value

        keys.some(p => {
          let value = parseInt(p);
          if (score >= value) {
            v = value;
            return true;
          }
        });
        this.results[key] = matrix[v];
      })
      resolve(this.results);
    })
  };

  createcharts(b) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Object.keys(this.results).forEach(key => {
        let el = document.querySelector(`#${key}-chart`);
        if (el) el.style.width = (this.results[key] / this.total * 100) + "%";
      })
      resolve(true)
    })
  };

  showresults(b) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //console.log(this);
      Object.keys(this.results).forEach(key => {
        let el = document.querySelector(`#${key}-score`);
        if (el) el.textContent = this.results[key];
      })
      resolve(true)
    })
  };

  warnuser(error) {
    let type = error.type;
    let msg = error.message;
    let content = type == 1 ? msg : `${this.warning}\n\nPlease correct: ${msg}`;
    alert(content)
  };

  analyse() {
    this.getscores()
      .then(b => this.calculate(b))
      .then(b => this.createcharts(b))
      .then(b => this.showresults(b))
      .catch(e => this.warnuser(e))
  };
};




document.querySelector('button#submit').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let app = new DiscModule();
  app.analyse()
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5em Lato, sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0.1rem auto!important;
}

.q {
  display: block!important;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.row {
  margin: 0.1rem auto;
}

[type='radio']:after {
  content: attr(value);
  color: black;
  background: yellow;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 1.5rem;
  top: -0.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.container>.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container>.row>section {
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.container>.row>section>.q {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

.pb {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  float: none;
}

.error {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)!important;
}

[data-score!=0]:after {
  content: '('attr(data-score)')';
  margin: 0 0 0 2rem;
  color: red;
}

.q {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.q:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.pull-left {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="badge">1</span><br>
            <br> Enthusiastic
            <br> Daring
            <br> Diplomatic
            <br> Satisfied
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
            MOST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="i-most" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="d-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="c-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1most" value="s-most">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
            LEAST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="i-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="d-least" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="c-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q1least" value="s-least">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="badge">2</span><br>
            <br> Intelligent
            <br> Decisive
            <br> Courageous
            <br> Heroic
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">MOST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2most" value="i-most" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2most" value="d-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2most" value="c-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2most" value="s-most">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">LEAST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2least" value="i-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2least" value="d-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2least" value="c-least" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q2least" value="s-least">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="badge">3</span><br>
            <br> Charismatic
            <br> Arrogant
            <br> Apathetic
            <br> Sociopathic
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">MOST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q3most" value="i-most" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q3most" value="d-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q3most" value="c-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q3most" value="s-most">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">LEAST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q3least" value="i-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q3least" value="d-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q3least" value="c-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q3least" value="s-least" checked>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="badge">4</span><br>
            <br> Apologetic
            <br> Obsequious
            <br> Attentive
            <br> Dominant
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">MOST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q4most" value="i-most" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q4most" value="d-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q4most" value="c-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q4most" value="s-most">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">LEAST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q4least" value="i-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q4least" value="d-least" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q4least" value="c-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q4least" value="s-least">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="badge">5</span><br>
            <br> Humble
            <br> Honest
            <br> Creative
            <br> Obedient
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">MOST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q5most" value="i-most" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q5most" value="d-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q5most" value="c-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q5most" value="s-most">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">LEAST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q5least" value="i-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q5least" value="d-least" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q5least" value="c-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q5least" value="s-least">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="badge">6</span><br>
            <br> Destructive
            <br> Demonic
            <br> Selfish
            <br> Spiteful
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">MOST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q6most" value="i-most" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q6most" value="d-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q6most" value="c-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q6most" value="s-most">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">LEAST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q6least" value="i-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q6least" value="d-least" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q6least" value="c-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q6least" value="s-least">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="q col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="badge">7</span><br>
            <br> Determined
            <br> Altruistic
            <br> Defiant
            <br> Valiant
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">MOST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q7most" value="i-most" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q7most" value="d-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q7most" value="c-most"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q7most" value="s-most">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">LEAST<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q7least" value="i-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q7least" value="d-least"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q7least" value="c-least" checked><br>
            <input type="radio" name="q7least" value="s-least">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>











<!--Progress Bar-->

<div class="col-xs-12 pb">
  <br>
  <p class="text-center">
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Calculate Results</button>
  </p>
  <div id="results">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <span class="badge">D</span>
      <span id="d-score" data-score=0></span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div id="d-chart" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-left">
      <span class="badge">I</span>
      <span id="i-score" data-score=0></span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div id="i-chart" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-left">
      <span class="badge">S</span>
      <span id="s-score" data-score=0></span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div id="s-chart" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-left">
      <span class="badge">C</span>
      <span id="c-score" data-score=0></span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div id="c-chart" class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thinking about the comment I made above, using `Set` might be one way to refine this.

Comment: thanks this works just fine. Thank you so much, Im new to stackoverflow so im not sure if im replying to you. i hope you see this thank you a lot. bless

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow... By default if you reply to an answer or a question the poster of that Q/A will see your comment.  I played about with the code and came up with a different approach which may, or may not, be of interest. see above edit

Comment: oh my thank you guys so much for your help. Bless you guys.